# html hyperlink download file issue

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I use absolute path `<a  href='N:\myName\test.xlsx'>download</a>`to download file from file folder. However, when I click it, the file is open directly instead of downloading it.

If I use relative path `<a  href='js/template/test.xlsx'>download</a>`, the file is downloaded before opening it.

My question is that how I can download the file instead of directly opening it using absolute path like

```
<a href='N:\myName\test.xlsx'>download</a>
```

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That absolute path is stored on your computer, which means it's a link to that file. You can't download something that's stored on your computer - it has to be stored on the web to download.

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for your quick answer. Why does the relative path work? Is it because it is on the web server?

Comment: Yes, it's on the server, which means it's not on your computer. That means that you can download it with the link.

Comment: Because we stored the files on a shared folder, how can I download them from my web page? Thanks.

Comment: So you want to download a file that's stored on a computer? There's no way of doing that short of uploading them to a web server

Comment: Hi Jack, because if I put the files under the tomcat project folder, the files will be deleted during next deployment. Do you know what the common way to handle this situation is? Thanks.